# Calling an object's method with the same name as another method

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a data structure that is backed by a HashMap. When implementing an add method, is there a way I can call the HashMap's add method from within my own add method?

Comment: Why not? That's what [Delegation Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just new a HashMap in your code such as:

```
HashMap h = new HashMap();
```

You can surely call `h.add(...);`.

On the other hand, if you inherit HashMap such as:

```
public class MyHashMap extends HashMap {}
```

You can call `super.add(...);` instead.